# Top half of donut disappears when trying to hide the icing

Tags: units

Doing the donut tutorial. Duplicated the top half of the torus, made it into its own object, unchecked Edit Mode in the Solidify modifier, clicked **Alt + Left Click** to select the bottom row of vertices, clicked **Invert** to get the top half, then when clicking **H**, instead of just hiding the icing, it hides the whole top half. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you did. When you create the icing you are supposed to copy the original torus then separate it by clicking P. You did not copy the faces of the torus that you needed. You simply took part of the torus(donut) and separated it as the icing and therefore left your donut as half. You can only see the problem right now because you are trying to hide it. So you have to go back to pat when you started creating the icing mesh and make sure you copy the faces first and leave the donut whole.

Comment: Like I said, I duplicated the top half.

Comment: Also, Can you try drag all the meshes side by side to see if the icing and top half could be joined objects?